# How to exchange text in PostScript

Tags: postscript

I do have the following content of PostScript code that is originally generated by the [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com) Printer on Windows XP.

```
/Euro /Times-BoldItalic /Times-BoldItalic-Copy BuildNewFont
} if
F /F1 0 /256 T /Times-BoldItalic mF 
/F1S52 F1 [82.664 0 0 -82.664 0 0 ] mFS
F1S52 Ji 
581 547 M (This is just a little test content)[55 42 42 23 46 37 42 37 28 21 51 42 21 51 46 42 32 66 42 21 60 42 55 21 21 21 55 37 32 46 55 42
23  0]xS 
;
```

I just want to edit the text but if I try to change the text between the brackets the text gets distorted no matter if the new text is longer or shorter.

I tried to understand what the code above does, but I didn't find an appropriative documentation for that.

Could you please help me to understand what the code - especially the line starting with '581' means and how I can edit the text without destroying the layout?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I need this for a python script that automatically exchanges some paragraphs and therefore am not looking for a third party tool for editing, a PDF editing tool or something like that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line starting with '581' apparently moves to the point 581 547 then pushes a string and and array which is used by `xS` somehow. I suspect that `xS` is an extended version of `show` that uses that array, but I don't know how. You'd have to look at the beginning of the PS file to find the definition of `xS`. Also `mFS` seems like a transformation because it gets a matrix.

Anyway, if the PS file contains typeset text, it's unlikely that you'll be able to change the text inside it without breaking the typesetting.

Comment: @Ihf thank you for that hint, you were right! Just a last question: Could you please tell me what the meaning of colon and semicolon is in Postscript? I didn't find them in any reference too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think colon and semicolon have any preset meaning but they can be defined to have anything, just like a named procedure. Look at the beginning of the PS file to find the definition.

Comment: @muffel, I've found a file to play with [here](http://www.megaskills.org/media/docs/source/EducationalAccountability.prn). `xs` is just `xshow`, which uses the array for displacing the letters. Hence the mess when you change the text length (and even if you don't). The colon means `gsave` and the semicolon means `grestore`. The definitions are near `%%BeginResource: file Pscript_Win_Basic`.

Answer (score 2):

The `xS` is almost certainly just `xshow` which is taking the string and the array and using the array to kern the text.  You can replace the text by using simple `show`.  Where you see:

```
(This is just a little test content)[...]xS
```

replace that with:

```
(This is my replacement content) show
```

The preamble of your file will have some shorthand name for `show` but you don't have to use it.  That text may still fail to fit, but if you're just changing an entry in a form or something equally isolated (a title, a footnote, etc) it will probably be fine.

If you want to get fancy you can take advantage of the fact that PostScript is a full-fledged programming language.  You could write a function which determines the width of the old string (for this `xshow` you would find the right edge from last element of the array plus the `stringwidth` of the last character of the string) and then computes the length of your new string (`stringwidth`) and then uses `ashow` to squeeze/stretch your string into its place.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @lhf. You really should do this sort of editing "upstream" fom the postscript level. Whatever the source application is, that's were the scripting needs to take effect. If the application has no native scripting then you can still interface to it with something like WinBatch. I've used WinBatch to make macro wizards to feed keystrokes to a telnet3270 client: enabling "batch" operations through the interactive system. For unix, there's expect.